# Drm function for dose response curve

Tags: r, label, axis, drm

I am trying to make a dose-receptive curve (i.e a titration curve). The data is

```
structure(list(Dilution = c(300L, 900L, 2700L, 8100L, 24300L, 
    72900L, 218700L, 300L, 900L, 2700L, 8100L, 24300L, 72900L, 218700L, 
    300L, 900L, 2700L, 8100L, 24300L, 72900L, 218700L, 300L, 900L, 
    2700L, 8100L, 24300L, 72900L, 218700L, 300L, 900L, 2700L, 8100L, 
    24300L, 72900L, 218700L, 300L, 900L, 2700L, 8100L, 24300L, 72900L, 
    218700L, 300L, 900L, 2700L, 8100L, 24300L, 72900L, 218700L), 
    X..bound = c(92.43, 92.95, 92.26, 86.55, 67.49, 21.86, 0.72, 
    89.57, 87.84, 82.35, 65.84, 24.18, 3.56, 0.32, 91.63, 90.57, 
    87.22, 77.03, 39.52, 5.39, 1.24, 93.51, 93.56, 90.33, 80.49, 
    38.97, 4.7, 0.93, 95.37, 94.44, 91.24, 77.74, 28.76, 2.14, 
    0.15, 0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.01, 0, 0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    Sample = c("CoV77-39 1mer 0DA", "CoV77-39 1mer 0DA", "CoV77-39 1mer 0DA", 
    "CoV77-39 1mer 0DA", "CoV77-39 1mer 0DA", "CoV77-39 1mer 0DA", 
    "CoV77-39 1mer 0DA", "CoV77-39 5mer 0DA", "CoV77-39 5mer 0DA", 
    "CoV77-39 5mer 0DA", "CoV77-39 5mer 0DA", "CoV77-39 5mer 0DA", 
    "CoV77-39 5mer 0DA", "CoV77-39 5mer 0DA", "CoV77-39 5mer 2DA GGG", 
    "CoV77-39 5mer 2DA GGG", "CoV77-39 5mer 2DA GGG", "CoV77-39 5mer 2DA GGG", 
    "CoV77-39 5mer 2DA GGG", "CoV77-39 5mer 2DA GGG", "CoV77-39 5mer 2DA GGG", 
    "CoV77-39 5mer 2DA GDGDG", "CoV77-39 5mer 2DA GDGDG", "CoV77-39 5mer 2DA GDGDG", 
    "CoV77-39 5mer 2DA GDGDG", "CoV77-39 5mer 2DA GDGDG", "CoV77-39 5mer 2DA GDGDG", 
    "CoV77-39 5mer 2DA GDGDG", "CoV77-39 5mer 2DA GDG", "CoV77-39 5mer 2DA GDG", 
    "CoV77-39 5mer 2DA GDG", "CoV77-39 5mer 2DA GDG", "CoV77-39 5mer 2DA GDG", 
    "CoV77-39 5mer 2DA GDG", "CoV77-39 5mer 2DA GDG", "CoV77-39 HA", 
    "CoV77-39 HA", "CoV77-39 HA", "CoV77-39 HA", "CoV77-39 HA", 
    "CoV77-39 HA", "CoV77-39 HA", "CoV77-39 WT", "CoV77-39 WT", 
    "CoV77-39 WT", "CoV77-39 WT", "CoV77-39 WT", "CoV77-39 WT", 
    "CoV77-39 WT")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -49L))
```

I then run `try<-drm(X..bound~Dilution,data=Titration.8.31,Sample,robust="mean",fct=LL.4())` and then this generates a curve after I run

```
plot(try,col=c("dodgerblue2", "#E31A1C", "green4", "#6A3D9A", "#FF7F00", "black", "gold1", "skyblue2", "palegreen2", "#FDBF6F", "gray70", "maroon", "orchid1", "darkturquoise", "darkorange4", "brown"),lty=c(1,1,1,1,1,5,5))
```

which looks great because the lines of best fit don't go below 0. However, I am not sure how to change the numerical axis; more specifically the x-axis. I am trying to make the x axis label with 10^.x---I know how to do this in ggplot by using

`+scale_x_continuous(trans = "log10",breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x)), minor_breaks = 10^(seq(0, 7, by = 0.25)))`

but this won't work with the plot function. Is there a way to make my x-axis label a 10^x# instead of the odd labeling/spacing it has now in the attached image? Or is there a way to do this in ggplot (preferred)?[image: graph with weird x label]

Comment: Step 1: Read the help page for `plot.drc`. Step 2: set `axes=FALSE` & redraw plot. Step 3. Put axes back in in that match your specifications using base graphics functions.  OR post MCVE

Comment: How do I use the base graphic functions to make a new axis label for my x-axis while leaving my y axis alone? (I am very new to coding so any advice is really appreciated. I really do appreciate your time too :) )

Comment: The help page for `plot.drc` describes parameters that can be used to change the ticks and tick labels. If you need more fine grained control then a review of your questions shows that you are not appropriately responding to earlier answers given.You might want to read the help page  https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I have looked at the page and tried to make the axes false and add in functions that change the axes; however, I am unable to get a good line written that R accepts. It spits out the error the the X and y axes differ in length when I try to change the x axes after the command axes=FALSE or it states that there is an unknown character or command from the .drc page is not found. Is there any advice on what to do after reading the help page? I was maybe thinking this: axis(side=1, c(10^seq(0,7, by=0.25)). I have also tried xtsy but that command in my plot string of functions also did not work.